# puppet intalled but stilll problem shown

Tags: rpm, puppet

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
root@niroj-SVE15118FJW:/home/niroj# rpmquery puppet
package puppet is not installed
root@niroj-SVE15118FJW:/home/niroj# puppet --version
3.4.3
root@niroj-SVE15118FJW:/home/niroj#
```

I am totally beginner for puppet and i encountered above problem.